# Hide scrollbar in Libre-Office Draw

Tags: libreoffice, drawing, libreoffice-draw

I know for sure, you can hide the scrollbars in Calc and Writer.
Is this also possible in Draw?

I am running:

windows 10

draw Version: 6.4.4.2 (x64)

Comment: Short answer: No. Long answer: you might be able to write an extension to do so, but that would be off topic here.

Comment: Aah man, thats a shame. I will ask around to see if anyone can help me with writting it then, Thank you!